# Running game server from bash without waiting for input

Tags: bash

I have a simple script which takes commands to start, stop, restart and return the status of a game server (SA:MP). The site provides the solution for using this command:

```
./samp03svr &
```

Which works all well and dandy however when the script executes this it holds and waits for user input (pressing ENTER) which then continues script execution.

I can't seem to find a way to keep the scripts execution without waiting for any user input. I've been searching for about 5 hours now and have tried at least 20 different things including running screen. Running screen worked just doesn't provide the exact thing I am looking for. The script also collects the process ID immediately after like so:

```
mv ./server_log.txt ./logs/server_$NOW.txt
mv ./mysql_log.txt ./logs/mysql_$NOW.txt
./samp03svr <<< echo &
pid=$!
echo $pid > $pidf
echo -e "The server has been started successfully"
```

The message that comes up waiting for RETURN is:

```
Started server on port: 7777, with maxplayers: 30 lanmode is OFF.
```

The server is running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear. You asking how to automatically press ENTER key?

Comment: I guess that could be one solution but I guess another could be just a way of skipping the command from waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because samp03svr outputs text, you need to redirect the output to null

```
 ./samp03svr > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to write a `newline` (`\n`) character to the standard input before running the server.

This is an example that write "foo" and pipes it to the std.in of the next command

```
echo $'foo' | while read x ; do echo $x ; done
```

So in your case you could do

```
echo $'\n' | ./samp03svr
```

Newline quoting example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13192701/1119345).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this only puts a linebreak in after the text which appears for the server starting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste this script somewhere, or the part of the script where it is trying to read ENTER key.

Also try this, assuming it waiting for newline:

> ./samp03svr <<< `echo` &

Comment: I think the hold is in the samp03svr but that file is complied since it is the server binary. I've updated the post with a larger snippet of the start up code in my script and the exact message its holding on.